# c# linq filter plus concat

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code:

```
    var data= from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                           group row by row.Field<string>("id") into g
                           select new { Id= g.Key };
```

I would like to add 1 more element to the data variable. How would I do it? (is there something like a data.Concat(1) etc

Comment: not sure how are you trying to concatenate here, but you are creating a new anonymous object here by using `new { Id = g.Key }`. So how are you trying to achieve the concatenation? perhaps `new { Id = g.Key + "1" }` is what you are looking for? (assuming g.Key is a string). An example of what you actually want to achieve would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how with query syntax, but you can use `Concat` with a single value by creating a new array of values with a single item:

```
IEnumerable<int> data = GetData()
    .Concat(new[] { "5" });
```

The problem with doing this simply is that your data is an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>`, which you can't simply new up, and I don't think new anonymous types are compatible with each other. (**Edit:** According to BrokenGlass, they are compatible.  You can try his solution instead).

If they aren't compatible, you could concat the item before your `Select` clause, but again, how do you create an item of that type.

The solution would probably be to select to an `IEnumerable<string>` first, concat, then re-select into your anonymous type:

```
var data = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("id") into g
            select g.Key)
           .Concat(new[] { "5" })
           .Select(k => new { Id = key });
```

Or to create a new named structure for your result, and concatenate one of those:

```
var data = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
           group row by row.Field<string>("id") into g
           select new MyCustomResult() { Id = g.Key };
data = data.Concat(new MyCustomResult() { Id = "5" });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add an additional Id you can indeed concat it:

```
data = data.Concat( new [] { new { Id= "1" } });
```

This works because anonymous types that have the same fields in the same order are compiled down to the same type.

Comment: +1.  I didn't know it would share anonymous types.  Thanks for the info.  If ever that doesn't work, you can see my answer :)

Comment: Be careful, because you will be creating another variable (the `newData`) in the memory, what isn't so good. I suggest you to use `data = data.Concat(new [] { new  { Id = "X" } });` if you want `Concat` without creating another variable.

Comment: @ErickPetru: Yes direct assignment is possible, I should have made that more clear in the example instead of introducing a new variable. I edited that in.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the LINQ result as a `List<string>`.
Generic lists can `Add` more itens easily.

```
var data = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("id") into g
            select new { Id = g.Key }).ToList();

data.Add(new { Id = "X" });
```

This way you will not need to declare another variable to hold the `Enumerable` with the new item (since an `Enumerable` is imutable and can't add new items to itself).

**EDIT:**

Like pointed, changing the `Enumerable<T>` to `List<T>` will put and hold all the elements on the memory, wich isn't a good performance approach.

To stay with the `Enumerable<T>`, you can do:

```
data = data.Concat(new [] { new  { Id = "X" } });
```

Because a `Enumerable<Anonymous>` can be placed inside itself.

Comment: +1 This is often a good solution.  The only problem with this (which isn't always a problem) is that it will evaluate the entire list and hold it in memory.  If you choose not to do this, then you can get a performance increase in cases where you don't actually need the entire list (especially if you consume this with code that uses yield returns).  On the other hand, if you ever have to dispose an object used in the query, this is definitely the best option, since it will work inside a `using` block :)

Comment: I totally agree your performance consideration. I'm updating the answer regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change from an anonymous type to a known type and then add that new element.

```
// ...
select new MyResultClass { Id = g.Key };

data.Add(new MyResultClass { Id = 4 });
```

Comment: No, you don't need. The language knows how to work with anonymous types.